# passing Struts 2 property to javascript method : getting weird values

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

In this example i wont to pass a property value (action attribute) to my js function like this:

Here is my Action class:

```java
public class XXXX {

    private List<String> numberCanBuyList;
    private float price;

    all getters and setters are used
}
```

Here is my jsp page:

```jsp
<s:hidden id="priceUnit" name="priceUnit" value="price"/>
<s:select id="canBuylist" name="bundle" list="numberCanBuyList" theme="simple" onChange="javascript:updateProperty('%{#priceUnit}')">
.....
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateProperty(n)
{   
var b = document.getElementById("canBuylist").value;
alert(n); 
alert(b);
}
```

***alert(n) show me : %{#priceUnit} and not the real value*** I'm doing wrong ?

I try also something like this, and i get the same behavior:

```
onChange="updateProperty(price)"> show me price
onChange="updateProperty('%{price}')"> show me %{price}
```

Comment: use '<s:property vaue="price"/> ' will work :)

Comment: <s:select id="canBuylist" name="bundle" list="numberCanBuyList" theme="simple" onChange="javascript:updateProperty('<s:property vaue="price"/>')">
I'm getting ERROR| equal symbol expected|com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.error(CommonsLogger.java:
38)
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /buy.jsp(29,143) equal symbol expected

Comment: check updated code and try now..Or try as Roman C told

Answer (score 0):

There's no such key `priceUnit` in the value stack. And Struts was trying to evaluate the expression `%{#priceUnit}` but fails to do it, so the value remains the same. But you don't need this expression if you've already got the value of `price` in the hidden field. To get the value from the hidden element you can use javascript like

```
<s:select id="canBuylist" name="bundle" list="numberCanBuyList" theme="simple" onChange="updateProperty(document.getElementById('priceUnit').value)">
```